# oracleADF 11g table refresh issue

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an adf table. Each column has a footer. These footers contain the sum of all the values of that column. The sum is calculated from a backing bean.

The issue is that the values are not getting populated in the footer with a table refresh. I have to do a page refresh to make them display the values. Doing a page refresh is not acceptable. Can some body help with this.

I have tried refreshing the table but that's not helping me.

Comment: Please, describe us in which way you are "refreshing" the table, or what are you meaning with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution,
I was refreshing the table using the following statement 
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(uiComponent);
where uiComponent is binded to the table. but when i did that only table is refreshing and not the footer. 
so what i did i created a panelgrouplayout around the table. now binded this PanelGrouplayout to the managing bean(private RichPanelGroupLayout uiComponent) 
now i refreshed the panelgrouplayout.using
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(uiComponent);
 when i did that its refreshing the whole table and footer.

Thank you